# How to call a function in the *.so file of a APK?

Tags: android, python, apk, decompiling

I decompiled a APK file, and found it loaded a external library like following:

```
 public class Encrypt
{
  private static Encrypt a;

  static
  {
    System.loadLibrary("encrypt");
  }

  public static Encrypt a()
  {
    if (a == null)
      a = new Encrypt();
    return a;
  }
...
```

And I also found the "libencrypt.so" file, then can I call the functions in it?
I tried following in Python, but failed

```
"OSError: ./libencrypt.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32".

    from ctypes import *
    encryptlib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libencrypt.so')
```

Comment: Isn't the ".so" created for specific processor? Are you running python on the same processor architecture?

Comment: The ".so" is from a Android APK file. I am running python code on a linux PC.

Comment: You're ".so" probably for arm processor. Although there might be x86 so available in the apk. If your linux machine has x86 architecture then you can probably use that code. If it is 64bit download the ia32 libraries.

Comment: you can check architecture information using `readelf -h *.so`

Comment: readelf -h libencrypt.so gives "Machine:   ARM"

Comment: You can probably use a virtual environment to call this. Although you might need to cross-compile python for that.

Comment: It sounds very difficult. Anyone do the same thing before?